# Setup Vim to indent only after colons

Tags: vim, vi

I am editing yaml files with Vim and oddly enough it indents every new line. How can I get it to only indent if I put a semicolon at the end of the previous line?

I have searched the internet, but I could only find some instructions on auto indentation, etc.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

YAML indenting should be more or less correct if you have *any* of the following lines in you `vimrc` and Vim recognises your files as `yaml`:

```
filetype indent on
filetype indent plugin on
filetype plugin indent on
```

[image: Demo]

Also, it's a *colon*, not a "semicolon".

Comment: The file is already recognized as yaml. That's not I'm asking. Everytime I press return, indentation increases by one step which is most of the time required only after a column, not key-value pairs.

Comment: The behaviour you want is the expected behaviour if you have any of those lines in your `vimrc`. If that's not what you have then there is something wrong somewhere in your setup, *of which we know nothing about*. For reference: `$ vim -Nu NONE file.yml --cmd 'filetype indent on'` looks [like this](https://i.imgur.com/cbDjBwG.gif).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using neovim, use coc-nvim. After installation of the coc-nvim install coc-yaml with command :CocInstall coc-yaml. After this, you'll get full support for YAML (syntax checker, syntax highligther, indentation, etc.)